# Batch resize .svg files

Tags: macos, automator, automation

I have a folder (original_svg_files) with more than ten thousand .svg files in different sizes and I need to resize each one of them. The name should be the same with the original .svg file and the longest side should be 150px and I also need to keep the aspect ratio (constrain the proportions).

I tried to use Adobe Illustrator to do that but can't figure out how since it supports only transformation via a percentage. I need to automate this process by the command line or Automator since what I am doing now is really time consuming!

I am using OS X El Capitan version 10.11.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the -fit option on this command line utility will do exactly what you want:

https://github.com/vieron/svg-resizer

If you need help with brew, look here: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/

If your not comfortable with the command line, don't let it intimidate you - it's really not that hard.  Post back if you get stuck or something just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use ImageMagick to do what you need. There is a homebrew package for Imagemagick (homebrew is the Mac equivalent of apt-get). So after a quick:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

You should be able to use the command line utilities for it. Looks like the convert command should do the resizing with the proportional scaling that you want.

```
convert oldimage.svg -resize "150>" oldimage.svg
```

This command says to shrink the image so that the longest side is 150. The rest is just using standard shell scripting to get the desired effect.

Comment: This broke the SVG format for me. It adds xml and doctype tags and the image no longer displays properly in a web browser.

Comment: this rasterizes the svg

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this works for mac shell too, but I wrote the following bash script based on the information on the [Inkscape forum](https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/batch-resize-svgs-in-a-folder/):

Basically it takes all svg-files and searches for the svg's viewbox attributes, adding width and height and a group wrapper to resize/scale down the original elements.

```
#!/bin/bash

for folder in $(ls -d [A-Z]*);
do 
  echo "$folder";
  mkdir -p resized/$folder; 
  for svgfile in $(ls $folder/*); 
  do 
    echo "$svgfile"; 
    cat "$svgfile" | \
      sed 's/viewBox="0 0 161.9 162" enable-background="new 0 0 161.9 162" xml:space="preserve">/width="41px" height="41px" viewBox="0 0 41 41" enable-background="new 0 0 41 41" xml:space="preserve">\n<g transform="scale(0.25)">/g' | \
      sed 's/<\/svg>/<\/g>\n<\/svg>/g' \
      > resized/$svgfile;
  done;
done
```

YMMV depending on whether your svg-files are all using the same original viewbox, mine did.

Comment: Why `$(ls $folder/*)` (which will break if some file names contain whitespace) instead of `$folder/*`?